# adc read accuracy ATMEGA

Tags: c++, avr, adc

I'm trying to read a bank of 6 Lifepo4 cells with an ATMEGA328P and I'm struggling to convert the 10 bit value to a voltage.

I'm comparing against a TL431 voltage reference that using my multimeter reads 5.005 volts

each adc pin is reading a voltage divider resistor pair 120k to ground and 510k to each cell, it works out about 26v to 5v scale

i have tried numerous conversions from pin value to voltage and they always end up close but out of scale and i can't understand why.

```
    #define AREF 501        /* 2 decimal places */
    #define maxVoltage 2630 /* 2 decimal places */

    // read the ADC pin value
    pinValue_Bank1[cellIndex] = analogRead(MPLEX_COM.Pin);

    // convert the pin value to a voltage
    //pinVoltage_Bank1[cellIndex] = ((uint32_t)pinValue_Bank1[cellIndex] * maxVoltage / 1024) * AREF / 500;
    pinVoltage_Bank1[cellIndex] = ((((uint32_t)pinValue_Bank1[cellIndex] * 100)+50) * maxVoltage / 102400) * AREF / 500;
```

the result is an int16 with 2 digits of decimal place

the +50 was shifting each value by 0.5 as a reading between 0 and 1 could be any voltage between 0v and 0.0256v i was aiming for the middle (it did not really make much difference)

comparing readings from ATMEGA and multimeter

```
 MULTIMETER     ATMEGA
 3.468v          3.41v
 6.940v          6.91v
10.440v         10.39v
13.560v         13.55v
24.950v         24.95v
```

the cells at the lower voltage readings are reading low and i cannot understand why.

am i going about the conversion formula completely wrong

Comment: What is the data type of `pinValue_Bank1`? Is it long, double, int? What is `AREF`?

Comment: Maybe my pocket calculator is broken, but what I see is less than 1% difference. And what is wrong? The multimeter or your measurement with ADC? Sorry, all around 5% is quite good. Remember: Your resistors will also have maybe 1% and there is electrical noise and also some non linearity on the ADC . But you got already <1%! Perfect!

Comment: @kiner_shah pinValue_Bank1 is uint16_t. AREF is a #defined compile time constant

Comment: @Klaus thanks, i think the multimeter is good, it gives me the same readings as my bench supply through a 0 to 60v range if its wrong, so is my bench supply, i think electrical noise is good, i have 100uf caps all over, any suggestions on how i would go about improving the results, i wrote a calibration offset that stores a byte in flash to offset against that works around the problem but i would rather not have to calibrate each cell individually unless there is no other way, this is an 80v battery with 3700 cell running my vehicle, calibrating individual cells would be a last resort

Comment: ` * maxVoltage / 102400) ` I think division operator will take precedence. You may need to first multiply and then divide. Try putting that `maxVoltage` inside `()`

Comment: You did not understand what I said! Your measurement is much more accurate as someone can expect! Measuring a voltage value with accuracy of 1% is perfect! What you want to achieve? Going to 0.1% means 10 times more accuracy which typically means 100 times more cost in electronics.

Comment: point taken, im expecting a lot from a simple 10 bit ADC. but the point still stands that i should be able to mathematically account for the inaccuracy of the ADC even if it were a calibrated value per board would still be better than a calibrated value per cell. i don't think that it is the inaccuracy of the voltage dividers because if it were the values would be randomly out of tolerance rather than consistently scaled out of tolerance. i will keep trying, thanks

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's essentially about hardware accuracy -- the accuracy of the as-build components and the accuracy of the ADC, which is well-documented in the part's datasheet.

Comment: @tomservo im voting to not care ether way, its all just a learning curve is it not, we strive to find the answer to things that are unknown to ourselves, yet reality is almost everything we could learn in our lifetime has already been learned by someone and has been documented somewhere. i guess you already new the answer i was striving to understand, curiosity though, if ADC accuracy is not relevant for a tag "ADC" what topics should be we discussing since everything there is to no about programming analog to digital converters has already been documented back when they were invented

Answer (score 0):

process of elimination i have found the problem.

there is nothing wrong this the code or the formula.

the inaccuracy is in bad wiring to the cells.

after successfully achieving 0.03v increments reading up to 26v with 120k / 510k resistive divider pair from my bench supply, i spot welded the wires direct to the battery cells and it works fine.

i tried 5 different circuit boards printed identically to check the tolerances between components and it seems reasonably good (although all the components on the boards were likely from the same batch next off the ribbon by the pick and place machine, so I'm not sure how good a test that was)

a side note would be make sure there is good capacitance on the AREF pin as close as possible to the chip, i also had issues reading values fast causing fluctuation in the REF until I increased the capacitance from 10uf to 100uf, I guess another option would have been to decrease the resistance powering the TL431 reference, but then it would consume more power

I guess you can't trust crappy spring terminals in battery boxes to make a good connection. but you can get reasonably good results with 10 bit ADCs if you put your mind to it.

the working code is as follows

```
#define AREF 501        /* 2 decimal places */
#define maxVoltage 2642 /* 2 decimal places */
uint16_t adcValue = analogRead(pin);
uint16_t voltage = ((((uint32_t)adcValue * 100)+50) * maxVoltage / 102400) * AREF / 500;
```

the result is int16 with 2 decimal places.

the +50 is assuming each reading is a value 0.5 greater than each reading red from the adc aiming for the middle of the possible values in each range

Answer (score 0):

As a note you could always determine the non-linearity and fit it to a second/third/fourth degree equation.
Take voltage readings from many of the boards and plot the results.
Then do a polynomial fit to the spread and apply the coefficients to your code.

ex:

```
#define ZERO_ORDER_COEFFICIENT 0.25f
#define FIRST_ORDER_COEFFICIENT 1.1f
#define SECOND_ORDER_COEFFICIENT .53f

// read the ADC pin value
pinValue_Bank1[cellIndex] = analogRead(MPLEX_COM.Pin);

// convert the pin value to a voltage
pinVoltage_Bank1[cellIndex] = ((((uint32_t)pinValue_Bank1[cellIndex] * 100)+50) * maxVoltage / 102400) * AREF / 500;

// apply second order equation to minimize error
pinVoltage_Bank1[cellIndex] = SECOND_ORDER_COEFFICIENT * pinVoltage_Bank1[cellIndex] * pinVoltage_Bank1[cellIndex] + FIRST_ORDER_COEFFICIENT * pinVoltage_Bank1[cellIndex] + ZERO_ORDER_COEFFICIENT;
```

The polyfit can help reduce the spread of the average error you see in the hardware.